# Transform data to data.frame with the pipe operator

Tags: r, magrittr

Lets say i have the following data: `x <- 1:2`.

My desired output is a `data.frame()` like the following:

```
a b
1 2
```

With base R i would do something along:

```
df <- data.frame(t(x))
colnames(df) <- c("a", "b")
```

**Question:**  How would i do this with the pipe operator?

**What i tried so far:**

```
library(magrittr)
x %>% data.frame(a = .[1], b = .[2])
```

Comment: Some base R options: `as.data.frame.list(x, col.names = c("a","b"))` or `setNames(as.data.frame.list(x), c("a","b"))`

Comment: You were almost there: `library(magrittr); x %>% 
  t() %>% 
  data.frame() %>% 
  set_names(c("a", "b"))`. The function `set_names` is from the `magrittr` package and can be replaced by `setNames` or `colnames<-` (enclosed in backticks).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After the `t`ranspose, convert to `tibble` with `as_tibble` and change the column names with `set_names`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tibble)
x %>% 
  t %>%
  as_tibble(.name_repair = "unique") %>%
  setNames(c("a", "b"))
# A tibble: 1 x 2
#      a     b
#  <int> <int>
#1     1     2
```

---

Or another option if we want to use the  OP's syntax would be to wrap the code with `{}`

```
x %>%
     {data.frame(a = .[1], b = .[2])}
```

Comment: Why do we need the weird `{}`?

Comment: @jay.sf  lol.  It  is not weird.  It is just to evaluate it as a single code block.  even `()` would be okay

Comment: Yeah, but the code inside `{}` looks self-contained to me, I don't understand the effect.

Comment: effect is the operator precedence

Comment: Ah I understand, `all.equal(x %>% data.frame(a=.[1], b=.[2]), x %>% data.frame(a=1, b=2))`.

Comment: @akrun What is the reason for loading `dply` and `tibble`, please? IMHO, `library(magrittr); x %>% 
  t() %>% 
  data.frame() %>% 
  set_names(c("a", "b"))` would suffice.

Comment: @Uwe I used `as_tibble`